# python script works from command line but not when it is executed from webapplication

Tags: python, command-line, groovy

I have a python script that does an operation like this:

```
  temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
  process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  process.communicate()
```

This seems to work perfectly file when I execute the script from command line. However, I have a need where my java web-application will be calling this script as an external process. I do that by:

```
    def command = """ /usr/local/bin/python ${myscript} ${arg1} ${arg2} """
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    def procOutput = proc?.in?.text
```

**Problem** is that when running the script from he we-app i get an error:

```
  File "/Users/anthony/script.py", line 34, in m
    process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the command `tesseract` is not part of the default PATH. It is best to give the full path to `tesseract` in your Python script, for example `/usr/local/bin/tesseract`; also make sure that the binary is executable by the same process that is launching the Python script.

In addition, make sure `path` is a fully qualified path, from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
os.chdir()
```

or force your programm to work with absolute pathes.